# How to find files from symbolic links with regular expression?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

My goal is to find certain files matching a certain regular expression. I'm using `find` command to achieve this goal. On a debian system the below command works perfectly.

```
find / -regextype 'posix-extended' -regex '^/etc/i.+/R.+'
```

The output is:

```
/etc/iproute2/rt_tables.d/README
/etc/iproute2/rt_protos.d/README
/etc/init.d/README
```

However, when I try the same command with a rhel system, the command outputs nothing. I know for a fact that `/etc/init.d/README` file is still there but regex cannot match it. I think it may be due to `init.d` directory being a symbolic link in rhel.

```
ls -l /etc/init.d
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Apr  4  2018 /etc/init.d -> rc.d/init.d
```

I couldn't rewrite the command to resolve symlinks. When I provide `-L` argument to `find` command the command runs in an infinite loop while outputting `find: File system loop detected;` infinitely.
Can you help me to rewrite the command? The best solution for me is to not change the regex since I don't generate this regex but I parse it from somewhere else. Thanks!

Comment: Start with `find -L /etc ...` instead of the root directory... or maybe just `ls /etc/i*/R*`

Comment: How do you know it is an infinite loop? What happens with: `find -L ... 2> >(grep -v 'File system loop detected' >&2)` ?

Comment: @Shawn as I've said changing the regex would not be a good solution for me because I parse the regex from somewhere else and the content of the regex is subject to change and yeah the first solution you proposed works in this case but what if there were other symlinks in /etc, would probably result in the same loop I think.

Comment: @jhnc yeah infinite may be a bit of a stretch but it is practically impossible to work with. The command works for more than 20 minutes outputting the same. However the grep solution works temporarily at least. It finds the file but the command keeps on searching.

Comment: What do you mean by `the same`? I would expect each message to refer to a different loop. Are you getting the same loop being printed over and over? Please add examples of some exact messages to your question. By the way, you should probably exclude places like `dev`, `/proc`, `/sys` from your search. Also, `-L` probably won't be reliable anyway as it depends on your desired path(s) being found first (before a loop).

Comment: I think your problem may be impossible to solve in the general case. Considier `touch f; seq 1 9 | xargs -n 1 ln -s .` and wanting to find `1/4/2/8/5/7/f`. Why should the search choose that particular path first out of the infinite number of possibilities?